# Index + Match not working as intended, only working for first instance

Tags: excel

The formula below is working sort of. its only working for the first date in the table tied to that person.

Cell C10 named "Date" automatically updates with the date when i select a date inside of a range. so if cell B2 has the date 01/01/2020, and i select it, cell C10 will now have the value 01/01/2020. Cell A1 named "Name" contains a name which is changed via a list in that cell.

i want the formula to find the row in my table that has the same name and date as the name and date in my worksheet, then give the cell containing the formula the value of column 5 of the matching row in my table

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(Date,INDEX(TblNotes[#All],MATCH(Name,TblNotes[[#All],[Name and Surname]],0),3),0),True),False)
```

Edit: ok so this might help people understand what im trying to say, ive got it to work now matching the date, i now want it to cross reference the name because if the the dates match it is showing me the value i want for the wrong person

```
=INDEX(TblNotes[#All],MATCH(Date,TblNotes[[#All],[Date]],0),5)
```

ok here is an example of what i am trying to achieve, and the setup is similar to mine
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkHoS.jpg

Comment: Your question it is not very clear... I can not see which information have you got in every excel datasheet and the names that they use. Could you upload some screencapture?

Comment: sorry i am not sure how to do that or how to explain it in a clearer way, i am a rookie. if i  had to really try to simplify it, how can i make the formula below match not just the first instance in a column

Comment: a better way of explaining, i want the formula to find the row in my table that has the same name and date as the name and date in my worksheet, then give the cell containing the formual the value of column 5 of that row in my table

Comment: You should upload something like this, because it is difficult to know how is your data setup. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPAmL.jpg

Comment: ok check my edit

Comment: It is hard to see your screen capture... what it is saying at the bottom? "This cell gets its value ???? I select a date, so if I call out ?????? value would be ????"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, where the date is in A1, the name in B1, and the table in G4:I7, you can use this array formula in C10/anywhere.... note it is an array formula and must be entered using CTRL+SHIFT+Enter:

```
=INDEX(G4:I7,MATCH(A1&B1,G4:G7&H4:H7,0),MATCH("Comment",G4:I4,0))
```

It's an array formula because there are two row match criteria in the first match function. Switching in the named ranges / named table, the formula looks like this:

```
=INDEX(TblNotes[#All],MATCH(Date&Name,TblNotes[[#All],[Date]]&TblNotes[[#All],[Name]],0),MATCH("Comment",TblNotes[#Headers],0))
```

(I assumed range B1 is named 'Name').

Comment: beautiful thanks a lot, its overwhelming how much there is to learn, i know so much more than an average user in the office and still i know next to nothing basically lol, so much fun to learn though

Comment: That's just how I feel too! Always learning. Cheers, glad I could help.